# How to add a python libary to a specific Blender build?

Tags: python, ppa, libraries, blender

So I have a build of Blender from PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

Everything works fine except one problem. I try to use an addon called "Animation nodes", than I try to enable it it cause this error:

[image]

In PPA I found this:

> For NumPy to work with Python 3.6 on Python 3.5 based distributions
>   (pre-artful), please install numpy with pip.

So I've installed it by typing `pip install numpy` in terminal. Now it looks like:

```
design@3dDesign:~$ pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But problem still exists.

Blender uses 3.6 version:
[image]

Maybe problem in versions? Or maybe I need to link Python in blender with numpy library in specific way?

Found outer addon called Shotpacker, also uses numpy and gets this error:

[image]

Нow to add numpy library?

Comment: Your running pip from the cli - it is using the py2.7 version of pip installed on the system. You need to run the pip command included with blenders install, [this may help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/56011/935). numpy should be included with the blender package, mention it to the owner of the ppa so he can update his builds. Can you manually import numpy in blender's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/path/to/blenderspython/python pip install numpy where /path/toblenderspython is the path to your version of blenders python directory. which may be `/usr/share/blender/2.79/python/bin/` based on your report error image.

Then try to enable your addon called "Animation nodes" again.

Sources:

[this comment from sambler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977311/how-to-add-a-python-libary-to-a-specific-blender-build#comment1569076_977311)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56011/how-to-use-pip-with-blenders-bundled-python